# Swift UITabBarItem as a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I tried to implement a `UITabBar` and now I am not able to retreive a callback from a method when an item was selected. Is there a possibillity to just create a `@IBAction func` therefore? Or do I need to do something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get callback/execute some code when a tab on Tab Bar is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667818/get-callback-execute-some-code-when-a-tab-on-tab-bar-is-clicked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to implement UITabBar button, your view controller should conform to UITabBarDelegate protocol. You need to implement:

Swift:

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!)
```

Objective-c:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

You also need to set the delegate (tabBar.delegate = self) in the viewDidLoad of your ViewController

Edit: Swift 3 answer:

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller should conform to `UITabBarDelegate` and implement:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item;
```

This method is called when the user selects a tab (i.e. `UITabBarItem`).

Comment: Do I have to call this method explicit in the code or when I implement it into the UITabBarDelegate is it going to be called automatically?

Comment: UITabBar will send this message to it's delegate when a user selects a tab.

Comment: `class MyClass: UITabBarItem, UITabBarDelegate {`

`class MyClass: UITabBar, UITabBarControllerDelegate, UITabBarDelegate {`

Which of these implementations are correct?

Also is this coding correct:
`func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {`

FYI I disconnected the default class and connected with the new customclass and it still not working (in `main.storyboard`).

Comment: Why are you subclassing UITabBarItem?

Comment: A tab bar item shouldn't be the delegate to the tab bar it's on.  You're probably writing yourself into a retain cycle.

Comment: @AdamWaite I just started programming swift 1 or 2 weeks ago so I didn't knew that I was subclassing. How can I fix this?

Comment: @nhgrif what do you mean with that? how should I do it else? Leave it on the default class? - I didn't understand it clearly

Comment: I think you need to get a book and learn the basics before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. I had some trouble with the Delegator-class and normal class.
This fixed my problem : `tabBar.delegate = self` in the Main-Controllerclass